# ffmpeg overlay background color/image with multiple videos

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm new to ffmpeg and I'm stuck not sure how to continue.

I have two videos that I will like to merge into a single video with background color/image overlay.

The image bellow is what I'm trying to achieve, the rectangle is the main video, the round is another video and the red is the background color/image.

[image]

video info: 
one.mp4 
original size: 1280x720
position/resized: (x20, y20, w980, h:keep-aspect-ration)

two.mp4
original size: 1280x720
position/resized: (x-bottom, y-buttom-left, w:keep-aspect-ration, h200)

So far I've only been able to add a bg-color but with a problem, the audio is gone, not to say that I haven't even added the second video as part of my command.

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=c=white:s=1920x1080:r=24 -i video.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:v][1:v]overlay=shortest=1,format=yuv420p[out]" -map "[out]" output.mp4
```

Any suggestion on how to achieve it?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The spec for two.mp4 is insufficient/unclear. Do you want to scale the video down to 200x112 then place the center of the circle at (180, 92) with the radius 20? (the numbers seem too small to be right imo)

Comment: the 200 was for the circle but I can what you mean since the round/circle is a mask on top of the two.mp4

Comment: I edited my answer with the new command. Give it a try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[edit 3/19: added full command for OP's need]

Try this:

```
ffmpeg -i one.mp4, -i two.mp4, \
  -f lavfi -i color=c=white:s=1920x1080:r=30 \
  -f lavfi -i color=c=white:s=400x400:r=1,\
              format=yuva444p,\
              geq='lum(X,Y)':'cb(X,Y)':'cr(X,Y)':\
                  a='if(lt((X-200)^2+(Y-200)^2,200^2),0,255)' \
  -filter_complex \
    [0:v]scale=980:-1[L0];\
    [1:v]crop=600:600:20:20,scale=400:-1[L1];\
    [L1][3:v]overlay=shortest=1[L2];\
    [2:v][L0]overlay=20:20:shortest=1[L3];\
    [L3][L2]overlay=W-420:H-420[vout] \
  -map [vout] -map 0:a output.mp4
```

- 1st `color` input (`2:v`): This serves as the background canvas. Its framerate `r=30` will be the output framerate.
- 2nd `color` input (`3:v`): This is the circular mask to the cropped `two.mp4`. Note that I fixed `geq` filter so the color is properly maintained (my earlier take was made for grayscale video)
- `one.mp4`(`0:v`) gets scaled to the final size -> `[L0]`
- `two.mp4`(`1:v`) is first cropped to square, capturing what to be shown in the circular cutout. `crop` arguments are `w:h:x:y` where the `x:y` is the coordinate of the upper-left corner. The cropped frame is then scaled to the final size (`400x400` in this example) -> `[L1]`
- The cropped and scaled `two.mp4` (`[L1]`) is then masked by `3:v` input to show through the circular cutout with the first `overlay` filter.
- `shortest=1` option for `overlay` filters to end when the videos ends (not `color` sources which will go on forever)
- The final two `overlay` filters places the 2 prepared videos to desired places on the canvas. Adjust its arguments as needed to change positions
- Because SD (720p) video inputs are converted to HD (1080p) video output, you may not need to do any scaling. If so, remove the `scale` filters from the filtergraph. For `one.mp4`, the first filterchain goes, so replace `[L0]` label with `[0:v]` in the modified filtergraph.

That should do it. As we went through earlier, when you run it, make sure to remove all the spaces, newlines, and backslashes in the middle of every filtergraph expression.

[original]

An approach I implemented in the past is to manipulate the masking image with `geq` filter. You can try the following:

For an illustration purpose, I use a rectangle with upper-left corner at (10,10) and lower-right corner at (1500,900) and a circle with its center at (1700,950) and radius 100.

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 \
  -vf color=c=red:s=1920x1080:r=1:d=1,\
      format=rgba,\
       geq=lum='lum(X,Y)':a='if(between(X,10,1500)*between(Y,10,900)+lt((X-1700)^2+(Y-950)^2,100^2),0,255)',\
      [v:0]overlay \
      output.mp4
```

- `color` source filter only generate 1 frame (1 fps for 1 second) and `overlay` apply it to every frame of the input video
- `color` output does not have alpha channel, so you need to convert to a pix_fmt
- `geq` sets the alpha values of all pixels: if coordinate `(X,Y)` is masked (so it assigns the alpha value of 255 = opaque) or True if `(X,Y)` is not masked (alpha = 0, 100% transparent). See [FFmpeg Expressions Documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-utils.html#Expression-Evaluation).
- `overlay` gets the input video stream `v:0` and overlays the output of `geq` filter on it.
- Because the filtergraph is implemented with `-vf` output option, inpnnut audio stream will be mapped automatically

[edit single line version]

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf color=c=red:s=1920x1080:r=1:d=1,format=rgba,geq=lum='lum(X,Y)':a='if(between(X,10,1500)*between(Y,10,900)+lt((X-1700)^2+(Y-950)^2,100^2),0,255)',[v:0]overlay output.mp4
```

Comment: Thanks @kesh, when ruining this command I got the fallowing error syntax error near unexpected token ('` and after putting all under a single stream `ffmpeg -I video.mp4 -vf 'color=c=red:s=1920x1080:r=1:d=1,format=rgba, geq=lum=lum(X,Y):a=if(between(X,10,1500)*between(Y,10,900)+lt((X-1700)^2+(Y-950)^2,100^2),0,255),[v:0]overlay' output.mp4` I got another error `Missing ')' or too many args in 'lum(X`

Comment: (1) I have an extraneous `'` right before `color` (fixed in the post) so pls remove (2) when you make it one long line, make sure there is no space after `,` of the filtergraph

Comment: Thanks, after the update I got another error `Unable to find a suitable output format for 'format=rgba,'
format=rgba,: Invalid argument`

Comment: I added the single-line version at the end of the post, give that a try (I know it's tricky to get it right)

Comment: I've tried the single version and faced an error. `Missing ')' or too many args in 'lum(X' [AVFilterGraph @ 0x123e0a050] Error initializing filter 'geq' with args 'lum=lum(X' Error reinitializing filters! Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument`

Comment: I must have the escaping incorrectly (I usually test it in Python and post what I think is the command line version). See what happens if you put a back slash (\\) in front of all the quotes `'`

Comment: Thanks, the script works although I'm not able to achieve what I'm looking for (maybe I've not formulated myself good enough in my question). What I get is a image/draw over the video

Comment: I think I messed up on my suggestion. For some reason I thought you have 1 video and 1 mask, not 2 videos and a mask. You can simplify the mask as the big video does not need to be masked. I'll get back to you in later today for a complete solution.

Comment: Could you add the sizes of the original videos (one.mp4 and two.mp4) and the locations of these videos on the output video: (x0, y0, w, h) of the one.mp4 and the locations of the circle on two.mp4 as well as on output.mp4. If you could add these info to your post, I can concoct the exact command needed.

Comment: I've added some info, let me know if it make sense. Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot, the new added command works!! the visual looks as it should, but the audio is not working, any idea on how to fix that?

Comment: What do you want to do? Which input's audio to play? Or do you want to mix both feeds?

Comment: I will like to keep the audio from one.mp4

Comment: Add second `-map` option as edited answer